# Javascript regex breaking in mozilla and IE

Tags: javascript, lookbehind

I am using `^(?= %)(.*?)(?=%)` regex for find out all the elements between % .
Test string is `"Hey %firstName% %lastName%"`.

It works fine on chrome but fails on mozilla and ie.

Comment: Could you provide an example of your code? That will allow us to more easily replicate the exact issue and help solve the problem.

Comment: This returns `null` in chrome for me: `"Hey %firstName% %lastName%".match(/^(?= %)(.*?)(?=%)/);`. I cannot reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

Here we go :

```
/%(\S.*?)%/g
```

Input : `Hey %firstName% %lastName%`
Output : `firstName,lastName`

Comment: i need only string surronded by %  %in output. In this I dont need Hey and ' ' in output.

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you need is to get the text bettween the %, you can try this:

```
\%(.*?)\%
```

Comment: Tried it? Regular expressions are greedy.

Comment: I tried this in youre fiddle and it works, it eliminates "%SurName%" and "%FirstName%"